Which ARIA role should a loading button have?
I have a form with a submit button. When the user clicks on the button, I need to perform an async action (e.g., an HTTP request to my backend).
To give feedback about the process, I disable the submit button and show a loader icon inside it, as most component libraries allow.
Some examples:

daisyUI,
mui.

Because I use <button />, the HTMLButtonElement automatically has a role=button, which is fine.
When the user clicks on the button, a loading icon appears for the duration of the async operation. In this case, the button behaves as a "progressbar".
From MDN:

The progressbar role defines an element that displays the progress status for tasks that take a long time.

which fits this case.
I'm confused about whether the button should have the "role=progressbar" attribute during the loading time or remain "role=button."
Should I update the HTML element specifying the role=progressbar or not?

You should never change the role of an element. It will confuse assistive technology (AT). You could disable the button, add a progressbar element and set focus on it. If focus stays on the button, I doubt that AT consequently picks up the changed accessible name that might include “Loading…”.

As Andy already pointed out in a comment, you shouldn't dynamically change the role of an element that is already exposed to assistive technologies.
Another important point is that a loading spinner is not a progress bar. A progress bar shows the level of progress, whereas a loading spinner just indicates that a process is going on without an indication of the level progress.
Something you can consider using is aria-busy=true on the container of the content that is being updated. Obviously, this is not the submit button.
